# Bootstrap: next to each other rather than on top

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Ok, 
I thought that

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <table id="example" class="display">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Property</th>
                    <th>Value</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <div id="container" style="height: 535px; margin: 0 auto">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

should result in a table next to graph. (Both objects are described in scripts). However on my private desktop both objects appear on top of each other...

Any ideas what i don't see here?

Comment: what is the css applied to the table?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

Comment: Ah, here was the bug. I didn't include href="http://...". Having said that, i can't believe I don't get a warning at some stage that my css file couldn't be found.

Comment: You generally do web development with the console open so you can see when stuff like this happens.

Answer (score -1):

Remember that the class `.col-lg-2` does not exist in bootstrap. You must use `.col-xs-2`. So just replace `<div class="col-lg-2">` with `<div class="col-xs-2">`, and you should be good. 
Good Luck!

Comment: I don't think you are correct here. See http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/. I have tried with md and xs, too. Same weird result. I use a large desktop though (1900 x 1200 pixel)

Comment: Technically I am, you can use either one, if that is not your problem though, I am not sure.